# Website Email Form (PHP) Issues

Tags: php, email, webmail

I know this is one of those things that gets asked a lot, but I'm not the most savvy web designer when it comes to more technical issues. The problem is this: on my website, www.imago-graphics.com, the email from the contact section doesn't go anywhere: neeither to my iPage inbox, nor my Google Apps email. I know it's probably an issue with the mail.php, but I'm not sure what it is. Here's the php (I've left the actual email address I want it to go to in the script (mariano@imago-graphics.com), but taken out the password; also, that address is a Google Apps email address, which I think might be part of the issue:

```
<?
require("class.phpmailer.php");


    //form validation vars
    $formok = true;
    $errors = array();

    //sumbission data
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $date = date('d/m/Y');
    $time = date('H:i:s');

    //form data
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];


$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                                         // send via SMTP
$mail->Host     = "smtp.gmail.com";                  // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                      // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "mariano@imago-graphics.com";          // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "xxxxx";               // Password

$mail->From     = "mariano@imago-graphics.com";          // SMTP username again
$mail->AddAddress("mariano@imago-graphics.com");         // Your Adress
$mail->Subject  =  "New mail from IMAGO Graphics";
$mail->IsHTML(true);  
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Body     =  "<p>You have recieved a new message from the enquiries form on your website.</p>
                      <p><strong>Name: </strong> {$name} </p>
                      <p><strong>Email Address: </strong> {$email} </p>
                      <p><strong>Subject: </strong> {$subject} </p>
                      <p><strong>Message: </strong> {$message} </p>
                      <p>This message was sent from the IP Address: {$ipaddress} on {$date} at {$time}</p>";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Mail Not Sent <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "Mail Sent";


?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that google is your smtp host? Are you using google apps?

Comment: Setting `$mail->SMTPDebug` will help you trace errors from SMTP, very helpful for gathering all the clues you need.

Comment: Matt: yes, I am using Google Apps, that email above is a Google Apps address. I know this is probably the root of the issue, but like I said, I'm more of a graphic designer than coder. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: MackieeE: Thanks, I'll look into that.

Comment: Are you sure your server can send (relay) email for `imago-graphics.com`?

Comment: Tigger: honestly, I'm not really sure of what the iPage server can or can't do. Their tech support isn't exactly helpful, they just tell me to get in touch with the developer of the templage I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few more params that you need to set to be able to send from a Gmail account. Please check their documentation on most up to date SMTP settings that you need to use.

These are couple things you have to have:

```
$mail->Username   = "mariano@imago-graphics.com";
$mail->Password   = "xxxxx"; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port       = 587;
```

During testing enable debug mode so you can see if the errors if there are any:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
```